# Qt animation filicker

Tags: qt, animation, flicker

I am trying to animate a QGraphicsItem, but I cant find a way to get rid of flickering. Item has a list of points (1.000+), and draws a polyline made of those points (like electro-cardiogram). I tried using double buffering (painting the line on a pixmap) and then animating, but flickering is still there. Here is the code for the item

```
Graph::Graph(float *data,int length,int frequency,QGraphicsItem *parent) : QGraphicsItem(parent),data(data)
{
    this->path = new QPainterPath();
    this->pixmap = new QPixmap(3*length,100);
    QPainter *p = new QPainter(pixmap);
    for (int i=0; i<length; i++){
        path->lineTo(3*i,data[i]);
    }
    pixmap->fill(Qt::black);
    p->setPen(Qt::white);
    p->drawPath(*path);
    setCacheMode(DeviceCoordinateCache);
}
```

and the paint method

```
void Graph::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget){

    QRectF area = option->exposedRect.toRect();
    painter->drawPixmap(area,*pixmap,area);
}
```

I am  using QProperty animation

```
QPropertyAnimation* animation = new QPropertyAnimation(graph, "pos");
animation->setDuration(70000);
animation->setStartValue(QPointF(0,0));
animation->setEndValue(QPointF(-1500,0));
animation->start();
```

Any ideas on how to improve the code?

Answer (score 0):

For your parent widget and on the widget on where animation is happening you can set this flag :

parentWidget.setAttribute(Qt::WA_NoSystemBackground);
animatingWidget.setAttribute(Qt::WA_NoSystemBackground);